# 'Currencysys' Object is not iterable

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with my model and serialization, I do a inner join of two tables like this:

```
# file views.py from Wallet
class WalletBalances(generics.ListAPIView):
      serializer_class = WalletSerializer

    def get_object(self, current_user):

        return Wallet.objects.filter(currencysys__id=F('currencysys_id'), 
                                 user_id=current_user)


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        current_user = request.user

        list_balances = self.get_object(current_user.id)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(list_balances, many=True)
        get_data = serializer.data

        return JsonResponse({'data': get_data}, safe=False, 
                              status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

the error shows me is = " 'CurrencySys' object is not iterable "

my file Wallet / Serialization is

```
from other_project.serializers import CurrencySysSerializer

class WalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      # currencysys = CurrencySysSerializer(many=True)
      currencysys = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Wallet
         fields = '__all__'
```

my models are:

```
# Currency / models.py
class CurrencySys(models.Model):
      currency_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
      currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
      currency_status = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
      currency_crypto = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

# wallet / models.py
class Wallet(models.Model):
      addresskey = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
      name_wallet = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
      currencysys = models.ForeignKey(CurrencySys, 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

why show me that error and how to fix this problem, please help me

thank for your attention.

Comment: What does `CurrencySys` means, in particular what the part `Sys` stands for? Why do you prefix the class attributes of `CurrencySys` with `currency_`. It's a terrible practice. Django will internally prefix them. Now you have totally messy column names in your database.

Comment: hi, CurrencySys is just a name, it was a type error my class is Currencysys, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currencysys` is a single ForeignKey object. So you dont need `many=True` argument for it:

```
class WalletSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      # currencysys = CurrencySysSerializer(many=True)
      currencysys = serializers.StringRelatedField()

     class Meta:
         model = Wallet
         fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: thank you, right I solved my problem but just show me fields a Wallet table, not the other fields Currencysys, please how to show all data like a "select * from ...."    please

Comment: @AngelOmarRojasPacheco In this case you need to remove `currencysys = serializers.StringRelatedField()` line and add `depth=1` to meta. See details here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization